# What does involutive span means?

Tags: linear-algebra

While I was studying a paper I saw "$Ω(x) := span({g_1(x),...,g_m(x)})$, is involutive."
But I do not under stand what it means.
I know that involutive function that has the property $f(f(x))=x$.
Also I know that $span({g_1(x),...,g_m(x)})$ means the set of all linear combinations of ${g_1(x),...,g_m(x)}$.
Also note that in the paper $g_i(x)$ is just considered to be smooth.
Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be helpful if you could tell us about the paper. For example, what is the title? Who are the authors? Can you give a link to an online version?

Comment: The paper is on Robotics, and this is one condition of columns of $g(x)$ in a dynamical system $dx/dt=f(x)+g(x)u$.
The link of the paper:
https://web.eecs.umich.edu/faculty/grizzle/papers/NAHS_2016_SubmittedVersion.pdf

First paragraph of page 6.